# Alter all occurence of href values with php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i want to change all the values of href tag before submitting them to database.

Lets say i have a paragraph with some anchor tags in it and i want to change the values of all anchor tags.

My goal is to base64 encode the urls and then append a prefix to urls 
if a urls is

```
http://google.com
```

before submission is want to change it to 
`http://exmaple.com/visit/base64encodeedurl`

Comment: can you please post some of your codes ??

Comment: @Drudge i havn't worked on it yet. but i found a code to replace all urls 
`$newurl = "http://myotherexample.com";
$pattern = "/(?<=href=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))/";
$newstring = preg_replace($pattern,$newurl,$string);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function and [`base64_encode`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) function

```
$string = 'Your string to save with http://goo.gl urls ...';
$fixedString = preg_replace_callback(
    '#[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,18}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]*)?#si',
    function($matches) {
        return 'http://exmaple.com/visit/' . base64_encode($matches[0]); 
    },
    $string
);
```

Here a live example https://3v4l.org/TUktY

Comment: i am getting this error
`PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Closure could not be converted to string in`

Comment: sorry I wrote `preg_replace` instead of `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: fixed to `[a-z]{2,18}` thank you for the reporting :)